# Publishing a stream using the Facebook API in PHP?

Tags: facebook

I am currently developing a facebook app and I would like to now how to publish to the users wall...
Thanks alot

Comment: Hey I just wrote a [blog post on this](http://fappside.com/2009/12/03/migrate-to-streampublish-before-december-20/). Let me know if it works and I will see what more can be done.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is FBML i would suggest using the FBJS call:

[Facebook.streamPublish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook.streamPublish)

This is not a php solution but it is more reliable as it doesn't require the current user to have accepted facebook stream permissions for your app.

For iFrame apps/ FB Connect the following is available [FB.Connect.streamPublish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.streamPublish)

Otherwise you can use the [Stream.publish](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish) rest api call available in:

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish
```

although this requires accepted app permissions